# Locating content in File on Linux system

Tags: linux, grep

I am attempting to search a log file on a linux system for a keyword.

If the structure of the log file appears below (it doesn't but this is a good example) and lets suppose I wanted to find the word "Hello" 
and the date and timestamp above hello and all the additional lines up the newline that starts the next record.

How would this be accomplished.

The only thing i could think of is a grep Hello -B 1 logfile.log.
This of course would get me one line before the matching content but what about the lines after up to the new line.  Also tried grep Hello -B 1 -A 1 logfile.log

Not sure how to get varying lines. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

[STRUCTURE OF LOG FILE]

```
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|

2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Richard|
Paul|

2015-01-01
Tchau|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Jerry|
Dwight|
Phil|
```

[DESIRED OUTPUT]

```
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|


2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Richard|
Paul|
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to use  `gnu awk` and divide data into block groups by setting `RS` to nothing.

```
awk -vRS= '/Hello/' ORS="\n\n" file
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|

2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Richard|
Paul|
```

If space between groups is not important:

```
awk -vRS= '/Hello/' file
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Richard|
Paul|
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-o`, `-P`, `-z` parameters with grep.

```
$ grep -ozP '(?s)(?:\n\n|^)\K(?:(?!\n\n).)*Hello(?:(?!\n\n).)*' file
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
2015-01-01
Hello|
Bob |
Billy|
Tommy|
Judy|
Richard|
Paul|
```